# Find local maxima points from contours OPENCV PYTHON

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, contour

I already have the code to find the contours of hand and to find the extreme points of the of the contour.

Now **I want to find the fingertips of the hand** for that the only approach comes to my mind is the **local maxima** technique but I don't know how to find these.

```
# import the necessary packages
import imutils
import cv2
 
# load the image, convert it to grayscale, and blur it slightly
image = cv2.imread("hand.jpg")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)
 
# threshold the image, then perform a series of erosions +
# dilations to remove any small regions of noise
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 45, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
thresh = cv2.erode(thresh, None, iterations=2)
thresh = cv2.dilate(thresh, None, iterations=2)
 
# find contours in thresholded image, then grab the largest
# one
cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
    cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)
c = max(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)

# determine the most extreme points along the contour
extLeft = tuple(c[c[:, :, 0].argmin()][0])
extRight = tuple(c[c[:, :, 0].argmax()][0])
extTop = tuple(c[c[:, :, 1].argmin()][0])
extBot = tuple(c[c[:, :, 1].argmax()][0])

# draw the outline of the object, then draw each of the
# extreme points, where the left-most is red, right-most
# is green, top-most is blue, and bottom-most is teal
cv2.drawContours(image, [c], -1, (0, 255, 255), 2)
cv2.circle(image, extLeft, 8, (0, 0, 255), -1)
cv2.circle(image, extRight, 8, (0, 255, 0), -1)
cv2.circle(image, extTop, 8, (255, 0, 0), -1)
cv2.circle(image, extBot, 8, (255, 255, 0), -1)
 
# show the output image
cv2.imshow("Image", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Example image:

[image: Example image]

Comment: Have you considered using scipy.signal.find_peaks to find the local maxima?